# Bring a column from one dataframe to another based on time(HH:MM:SS) value in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes,
df1 has a column "Time" and df2 has 3 columns "Start Time", "End Time" and "Value"
all the time based columns are in HH:MM:SS format and are of object type.

I want to bring column "Value" from df2 to df1 based on time's column, i.e. if df1["Time"] is between the df2["Start Time"] and df2["End Time"] then put that respective value against the "Time" column in df1.

**Below are my input dataframes:**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['10:27:30','6:27:00','14:57:59']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Start Time':['10:20:33','05:53:42','15:00:00'],
 'End Time': ['11:20:33','06:28:42','15:30:59'],
 'Value':[123,360,100]})
```

**required output in df1**

[image]

I am tryting to do something like this

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start Time'])
df2['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End Time'])


if (df2['Start Time'] <= df1['Time']<=df2['End Time']):
    df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Key1','Key2'],how='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use cross join between both DataFrames, then filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and last add missing rows by right join:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'].astype(str))
df2['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start Time'].astype(str))
df2['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End Time'].astype(str))


df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
df = df[df['Time'].between(df['Start Time'], df['End Time'])].merge(df1, how='right')
print (df)
                 Time          Start Time            End Time  Value
0 2022-02-25 10:27:30 2022-02-25 10:20:33 2022-02-25 11:20:33  123.0
1 2022-02-25 06:27:00 2022-02-25 05:53:42 2022-02-25 06:28:42  360.0
2 2022-02-25 14:57:59                 NaT                 NaT    NaN
```

Last if need times:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time
df['Start Time'] = df['Start Time'].dt.time
df['End Time'] = df['End Time'].dt.time
print (df)

       Time Start Time  End Time  Value
0  10:27:30   10:20:33  11:20:33  123.0
1  06:27:00   05:53:42  06:28:42  360.0
2  14:57:59        NaT       NaT    NaN
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael while running the first three lines I am gettin a TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @Annu - answer was edited - 3 times by `.astype(str)`

Comment: Hi @jezrael I am getting this error while running on an entire data frame 
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.05 TiB for an array with shape (144535733112,) and data type int64